# Space of functions on $[a, b]$ with countable discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We are quite familiar with $C([a,b])$, the set of all continuous functions defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$ with the supremum norm. My question is; if we allow function with countable discontinuity what will change? I think everything will change but I do not know how to approach this problem. As an example if I allow countable discontinuity is the usual norm valid in $C([a,b])$ is applicable? What condition we need to impose to make the space complete? Etc. Is this space studied in depth? I could not figure out much in the literature. Any suggestion?

Comment: I guess you might be interested in the space of functions with bounded variations (i.e. BV[a,b]), which is a Banach space allowing functions with jump discontinuities. See Wiki [Bounded Variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one particular example:

If we consider Lebesgue measure, then we can consider $L^\infty([a,b],m)$, which has a norm given by $$\|\cdot\|_\infty \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} \operatorname{ess} \sup_{[a,b]} \cdot.$$

The essential supremum is defined as the smallest upper bound $a$ of $f$ such that $m\left(\{x : f(x) > a\}\right)) = 0$. This space is complete with respect to the topology induced by the $\infty$-norm provided that our measure space is semi-finite. Below is a (probably ham-handed) outline of the proof of completeness.

Let us take an absolutely convergent series in $L^\infty([a,b],m)$ converging to $f$. Then $\sum_1^\infty \|f_k\|_\infty = B < \infty$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, consider a set $B_\epsilon = \{ x : f(x) > \|f\|_\infty - \epsilon\}$. Now, take a finite-measure subset $A$ of $B_\epsilon$.

On $A$, we have $|f_k| < \|f_k\|_\infty$ by definition, so we must have $\sum_1^\infty |f_k|$ converging, and in fact, the convergence is uniform. Thus, we must have $|f_k - f| \to 0$ on any set with non-zero finite measure. In a normed vector space, we have that the space is complete iff every absolutely convergent series converges in the space, so the space described above is in fact complete.

Comment: Note that this is a restriction to a specific instance of the situation described by the OP, and is not intended to be a catch-all for every possible such function or function space. Just an example of something satisfying the OPs criteria that is interesting.

Comment: Interesting example, thank you.  May I ask in the note what you mean by OP?  Is there a name of this space?

Comment: In this case, "OP" means you :) "OP" means "original poster", which here often refers to the person who asked the question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way this question came as i am interested to see if such a space can be used to certain ill-posed  problem. Any comments; please?

Comment: I don't know. There's a lot to it. In a sense, if we consider all $L^\infty$-integrable functions, then they are "well-behaved" in the sense that countably many discontinuities doesn't interfere with our "integration." So if you have a function with a finite essential supremum, you don't care about countably many discontinuities. In essence, it allows you to ignore the annoying bits of the function.

Comment: Thank you. Agreed and and understood. I am only exploring the possibility of applying the countable discontinuity functions.