# Space of function with countable discontinuity.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am asking this question just to make sure that I am concluding correctly that a function which is zero everywhere except at certain points; is within the set of space of function with countable discontinuity as referred in the link:

[Space of functions on $[a, b]$ with countable discontinuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284041/space-of-functions-on-a-b-with-countable-discontinuity)

A confirmation would be appreciated. If the function is defined on t it means that function is zero everywhere on t except at certain t.

Comment: What do you mean by at certain points?

Comment: After writing it, I realized it is not clear. sorry. Consider f(t) is compact between [a,b] and t is continuous. I mean points as a value at certain t  only and zero everywhere on t.

Comment: It is still not clear...... Is $f$ continuous except finitely many point? Countably many points? Or even worst?

Comment: Countably many poinys

Comment: OK. So if $f$ is continuous except at finitely many point, then by definition it is inside that space. But, for example, if $f$ is nonzero except at countably many point, then it might not be in that space, for example, if $f$ is $1$ for all rationals and zero otherwise, $f$ is nowhere continuous.